# Multiple configurations for one OpenIdConnect service

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, identityserver4, startup

I have two URLs that can be directed to my web app. Depending on the URL, I want to change what OpenIdConect (OIDC) configuration to use.  I want to be able to do this without restarting the app. This requirement came after the web app was created and now needs to support two URLs.

Let's say the URLs are:

- internal-mywebapp.company.com
- mywebapp.company.com

The original code in `Startup.cs : ConfigureServices` :

```cs
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{                    
    options.SignInScheme = oidcOptions.CookieSchemeName;
    options.Authority = oidcOptions.AuthServerUrl;
    options.ClientId = "ExternalClientId";
    options.ClientSecret = oidcOptions.ClientSecret;
    options.ResponseType = oidcOptions.ResponseType;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    foreach (var claim in oidcOptions.RequestClaims)
    {
        options.Scope.Add(claim);
    }
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("sid");
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider =
        EventsOnRedirectToIdentityProvider(applicationOptions);
    options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = EventsOnRemoteFailure();
})
```

Now, my thinking is to add code the the `Configure` method and, if the URL starts with 'internal', use the configuration for 'internal'.  I'm newer to configuring a web app to use authentication providers so I'm not too aware of the possibilities.

One thing that came up when researching this was to add a second OIDC block to `AddOpenIdConnect` like this and then do something in the `Configure` method to switch to the needed configuration :

```cs
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc-external", options =>
{                    
    options.SignInScheme = oidcOptions.CookieSchemeName;
    options.Authority = oidcOptions.AuthServerUrl;
    options.ClientId = "ExternalClientId";
    options.ClientSecret = oidcOptions.ClientSecret;
    options.ResponseType = oidcOptions.ResponseType;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    foreach (var claim in oidcOptions.RequestClaims)
    {
        options.Scope.Add(claim);
    }
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("sid");
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("userLdapid", "userLdapid");
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("fpUserRole", "fpUserRole");
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("userType", "userType");
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider =
        EventsOnRedirectToIdentityProvider(applicationOptions);
    options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = EventsOnRemoteFailure();
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc-internal", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = oidcOptions.CookieSchemeName;
    options.Authority = oidcOptions.AuthServerUrl;
    options.ClientId = "InternalClientId";
    options.ClientSecret = oidcOptions.ClientSecret;
    options.ResponseType = oidcOptions.ResponseType;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    foreach (var claim in oidcOptions.RequestClaims)
    {
        options.Scope.Add(claim);
    }
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("sid");
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("userLdapid", "userLdapid");
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("fpUserRole", "fpUserRole");
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("userType", "userType");
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider =
        EventsOnRedirectToIdentityProvider(applicationOptions);
    options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = EventsOnRemoteFailure();
});
```

I could be overlooking a different approach as posts I have found sort of hint that this can be done but nothing quite fit.

Comment: If the data structure looks like same except for the values, then [bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern) might help. Bind one for internal and the other for external, respectively.

Comment: Can you suggest how I would switch between the two with example code?  My requirements are for each request I look at the URL and change which configuration I use so that the user gets is sent to my IdentityServer service with the correct configuration (namely the ClientId).

Comment: ¿Same app on two different domains, login users through a SINGLE identityserver?

Comment: @PabloRecalde :  Yes, that is correct.  Two different domains pointing to one app and that one app interacts with the single IdentityServer.

Comment: Then you just need to add those domains to your identityserver's client configuration not the other way around. Aspnetcore middleware will choose the correct url for the authorize request, so if both are configured as allowed to do the oidc flow, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

@PabloRecalde : I'm not sure if was entirely clear of what I wanted.

To rectify this, we decided to split out the same code base into two separate instances with the help of our CI/CD pipeline. We were trying to use the same instance and figure out a way to switch between two OIDC based on the host name for each request.  This proved difficult.